# Who is Abu Musab Wajdi Akkari?

Tags: dawah, islamic-scholar

There are several lectures of Abu Musab Wajdi Akkari on multiple topics which are appealing but I still don't know whether he is a qualified scholar. He criticizes a lot of scholars and sects like Sufis, Shia etc.
Can anyone who knows or from his area elaborate on him?

Comment: If you want to know about his life, you can check his video titled "The Helpless Slave of Allaah (Abu Mussab's Story)" or his [official youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/OneWayToParadise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abu Mussab Wajidi Akkari was born in Lebanon to a Christian family. He celebrated all festivals but later reverted to Islam by the leave of Allah. There is an entire documentary on him on Youtube ([From Rock Bottom to The Surface](http://youtube.com/watch?v=CFerTkShRBI))

He travelled to the USA to become a rapper. He accepted Islam in Los Angeles (not to forget he was a Buddhist in between too). He is currently associated with Jeddah Dawah centre in Saudi Arabia.

As far as his lectures are concerned, they are just about right if you subtract the criticism part. Prohibiting from a wrong action is just right and he does it. But sometimes he goes a bit above the safe levels. Allah is the judge though and its always better to be on the safe side.

And yes, he has the skills of explaining things in a modern way.. +1 for that.

Comment: `Abu Mussab Wajidi Akkari was born in Lebanon as a Christian`. That clearly contradicts his biography @ http://www.onewaytoparadise.net/about.php? Where did you get that from?